# What are the rules that determine the default contents of an /etc/hosts file?

Tags: networking, hosts, ip-address

What are the rules that decide what goes into the initial /etc/hosts file of a a server with these characteristics?

1. It has a internal IP address for the internal subnet. which is in the 172.20.x.x range
2. It has a public facing IP address which has a 1 to 1 mapping with the internal IP address

`ifconfig` only shows the internal IP address, which is 172.20.x.x,which doesn't seem to be part of the range reserved for internal networks (which is what has me somewhat confused)

Comment: FWIW, RFC1918 covers 172.16.x.x->172.31.x.x (amongst others) and so your 172.20.x.x is definitely inside the private range; https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1918

Comment: What goes in it initially is whatever your distro decided. Usually an entry for 127.0.0.1 and for the primary address on the first interface you configured during installation, if you chose a static address. What distro are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- first rule

  syntactically correct
- second rule

  logically true
- third rule

  depends on your distro.

I'd expect an entry for localhost and possibly for the system's hostname.
localhost may be an ipv6 entry (`::1`) in which case there may be an additional entry for ipv4-localhost

What you should you put in the hosts file is any IP address to domain name relations that you do not want to rely on DNS to determine.  This is not default, this is customisation.

Comment: Fourth, site specific rules, e.g. to use configuration management to enforce the contents of `hosts` so that stray debug or test entries are less likely to end up backstabbing you X months down the line. Fifth, a ruthless devotion to the ...

Answer (score 1):

**`172`**, **`192`** and **`10`** are the IPv4 first-octets used for private networks.  The standard specifies ranges of values for the second octet.  For **`172`**, that's **`16`** through **`31`**.

The usual practice for `/etc/hosts` is to provide a loopback address, which is apparently your **`172`** address.  If you have both IPv4 and IPv6 configured, a separate address/hostname is needed for each loopback.

Often (but not required, and strongly dependent on other parts of your network configuration) people add the fully-qualified domain-name and hostname in `/etc/hosts`.

How the public IP address shows (or does not) depends on what devices you have configured.  AWS does not normally show public addresses, as noted in discussion *[why does ipconfig not sure elastic ip?](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=385448)* , but you may be configuring for some other system (even a standalone server).

Further reading:

- [IPv4 Private Address Space and Filtering](https://www.arin.net/knowledge/address_filters.html)
- [Amazon EC2 Instance IP Addressing](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/using-instance-addressing.html)

Comment: Massive over simploification (to the extent that it's wrong) also does not answer the question.